# What causes the difference between HTML5 video metadata reading and commercial products?

Tags: javascript, html5-video, adobe-premiere

When using Premiere Pro I have a file that is 2:45:23 seconds, 4973 frames at a 29.97fps rate.

When loading the same file using JavaScript and video.duration I get rounded 166 seconds using Math.round (3 min 16seconds) which using simple logic here (I'm not good at math to begin with) gives me (166seconds * 29.97fps) = 4975 frames.

Part of me wants to say this is due to some header frames storing the metadata that Premiere strips out, but I'm actually curious as to the loss of precision.

Any accurate idea?

Comment: 166 seconds is 2 minutes 46 seconds, not 3:16, so it is almost the same as what Premiere Pro outputs.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is a rounding error -- since the 166 second time is not precise, the number of frames you compute from it is not, either.

Comment: Understandable, however there's obviously not an additional ~30seconds of video...so while the raw duration is about 165.7xxxxxxx seconds why would Premiere see it as 2:45 seconds?

Comment: Additionally Windows Explorer shows it as 2:45 is there some time period that the video api in a browser wouldn't show this?

Comment: @Shawn: Those displays must be rounding down to get 165 seconds rather than 166.